# How do i debug my query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to insert some data to the mysql database

```
$db = new DataBase($config);

// connect to the database RETURNS true if success false if fails
$conn = $db->connect();

// check whether the connection is successfull or not...
if ($db->isConnected())
     {

        //prepare the query
        $query = 'INSERT INTO scoreboard (score) VALUES(:score) WHERE username=:username';
        $bindings =  array(
                         'score'   =>  $score,
                        'username' => ($_SESSION['username'])

                         );


        // call the query function from db class and retrieve the results as an array of rows.
        $results = $db->setData($conn,$query,$bindings);
        if ($results)
            echo "Your Score is Updated!";
        else

            echo "Your Score is Not Updated!";


        }
```

Heres what setData() does :

```
function setData($conn,$query,$bindings)
{
    try {

            // prepare the query
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

            //binde the query with the data .here the data is $bindings
            $stmt->execute($bindings);

            return ( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 )
                // return the result if the query is success else return false.
                ? $stmt
                : false;
        } 

        catch(Exception $e) {
            // return error if something goes wrong
            return false;
        }


}
```

Everytime I run this script I get "Your Score is Not Updated" as output.

Where I am going wrong?

Is that the $_SESSION['username'] causing trouble?

Any help with proper explanation will be highly appreciated!

Comment: what does `$db->setData` do? I think it's for select..

Comment: Have you enabled error reporting? Have you correctly set your db connection to throw up or show errors? What does `setData` do? We have no magical way of knowing what is happening in code we don't know about. Is there a specific reason you wrapped PDO in another class?

Comment: @PeeHaa :No such specific reason

Comment: Have you checked out the exception that might get thrown?

Comment: @PeeHaa Did u mean something like this : return $e->getMessage(); ?

Comment: I think you need update rather that insert

Comment: `var_dump($e)` You are catching the exception and simply return `false` preventing you from doing any decent debugging

Comment: @PeeHaa I did print the exception varibale ..it shows "NULL";

Comment: if you want to use $_SESSION, you need to place session_start() at the beginning!

Comment: @PaoloNiccolòGiubelli session_start() is initialized ..i think the query is causing the trouble .

Comment: @PeeHaa Do i have to enclose the query in double quotes??

Comment: Are you inserting duplicated data?

Comment: You are using PDO, arent't you?

Comment: @Paulo Niccolo Giubelli yes I am

Answer (score 0):

you are updating or inserting? try your query manually with static data on phpmyadmin, then make sure your session is set & return true if successfully data inserted